# Uploading Text File via HTTP using vbscript

Tags: php, html, vbscript, webserver

I want to upload a text file from local drive to web server by HTTP using vbscript. How to do this?  I need to upload a .txt file into server .

Vbscript code I used:

```
strUserID = "******" 
strPassword = "******" 

  strURL =   "http://testpias.site50.net/http/up.php"

Set HTTP = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")



Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 1
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile "G:\Http\http.txt"




HTTP.open "POST", strURL & "http.txt", False , strUserID , strPassword
WScript.Echo "Now uploading file " & "G:\Http\http.txt"


HTTP.send objStream.Read


 WScript.Echo "Uploading complete for file " & fso.GetFileName(File)




WScript.Echo "All files uploaded."

Set HTTP = Nothing
```

PHP code I used to receive the file :

```
<?php

        $file_path = "http/";

        $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
            echo "success";
        } else{
            echo "fail";
        }
     ?>
```

But I got this  error while I ran the vbscript ,  " Access is denied " .

Comment: I would advise using `POST` via HTTP. Since you added `PHP` as a tag, I would suggest maybe using a PHP script to accept the `POST`. Performing WebDAV via VBscript can be difficult if the server even supports to protocol.

Comment: Thnks for your reply . I used "POST" and a php file to receive data , but know luck . My code replied " Access is denied " , I'm updating the code I used . pls suggest  me a solution .

Comment: Sorry to say, but that error could be spawned by a lot of things. You'll want to add some error checking all throughout. Verify that you can create the HTTP Object, File System Object etc. Maybe your script cannot read from `G:\Http\http.txt`. Also your POST looks malformed. It has to be setup and formatted correctly.

Answer (score -1):

For your VBScript, I would suggest the following (not using `PUT`):

```
Dim strURL, HTTP, dataFile, dataRequest
Dim objStream As Object
strURL = "http://testpias.site50.net/http/up.php"
Set HTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

objStream.Type = 2
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile "G:\Http\http.txt"
set dataFile = objStream.Read
set dataRequest = "dataFile=" & dataFile

HTTP.open "POST", strURL, False
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(dataRequest)

WScript.Echo "Now uploading file G:\Http\http.txt"

HTTP.send dataRequest
WScript.Echo HTTP.responseText

Set HTTP = Nothing
```

Then in your PHP that will accept the file, you have to do some work too. Making sure that your handler is looking for the right index. Also we want to return some response so we know what happened.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_FILES['dataFile']['error']) || is_array($_FILES['dataFile']['error'])) {
    switch ($_FILES['dataFile']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            echo 'Unable to Upload. No file sent.';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            echo 'Unable to Upload. Exceeded file size limit.';
        default:
            echo 'Unable to Upload. Unknown errors.';
    }
    die();
}
$file_path = "http/";
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['dataFile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['dataFile']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "File {$_FILE['dataFile']['name']} uploaded success";
} else{
    echo "Unable to upload. Unable to move uploaded file.";
}
?>
```

Sorry I do not have the ability to test this. Hopefully this will get you in the right path.

Reference: http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_read-write-binary-files/

Comment: thanks very much for your reply . I got an error in vbscript .  in this line `set dataFile = objStream.Read ' read binary ' ` , the error is " Object Required " . pls help

Comment: This would suggest that the line before did not create the object. I added a few bits of code. Also make sure the File exists at the path and has correct permissions.